# Is there a way to avoid returning `any` within a JSON.parse reviver?

Tags: json, typescript, eslint

I have a project using TypeScript and ESLint.  I need to deserialize a JSON string, and want to take advantage of the [optional reviver parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter).  A reviver function basically lets you conditionally transform values as part of the JSON deserialization.

The signature of the reviver function is defined as part of the JSON.parse specification, which is:

```
JSON.parse(text: string, reviver?: ((this: any, key: string, value: any) => any) | undefined): any
```

In particular: it takes in a `value` of type `any` and returns a value of type `any`.

```
const deserializedValue: unknown = JSON.parse(serializedValue, (key, value) => {
  if (value === 'foo') {
    return 'bar
  }
  return value
}
```

I'm scolded by ESLint because when I write `return value` I am returning something of `any` type:

```
  5:4  error  Unsafe return of an `any` typed value  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
```

Is there a way for me to programmatically avoid the linting complaint about `any` types within the constraints of the unknown nature of deserialization, or do I have to disable the linting rule for that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eslint is a bit overzealous here. Or at least that rule doesn't apply well to this case.

Parsing JSON is an inherently type unsafe process. In this case the `any` is just passed through from the argument type, and the function is typed in a place you can't control to return `any`.

So I'd probably just cast it to `unknown` like:

```
return value as unknown
```

Which sort of makes it clear that "I don't know or care what this is". And the return type does matter because anything matches `any` and the return type is used in the return type of `JSON.parse()`.

This [seems to work](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.7.2&sourceType=module&code=CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3mkMCWUEeAXiMAGqECuIAXNhvigOYBQry6WoO+hJZShBrwAvPABSAZQDyAOQB0AB1g4AFLwJFSFaiAA08NQGsQAT0MA3PQEoxAPngBvVvHh4AZkevCEo--AA5B5ISIF2Lm5ucBhUMChBAEawga7wAL5pMXEJPiJQaPBUKMYoSADuKKzpNkA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQAIBcBPABxQGNoBLY-AWhXkoDt8B6Jge1tieQEMAZolrRE+WNCbooiaNA7RI4MAF8QKoA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA).

But that's probably not that much better than disabling the rule for that line either. Which is right is more a matter of opinion.

But still, I'd go with the `as unknown` cast.

Comment: Thank you!  I also realized I can cast `value` to unknown in the inline function definition `(_, value: unknown) => ...` which somehow feels a bit nicer than `as unknown`.  At any rate this does the trick thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to *reset* this return type by installing [ts-reset](https://github.com/total-typescript/ts-reset) as a devDependency.

```
// Import in a single file, then across your whole project...
import "@total-typescript/ts-reset";

// Get rid of the any's in JSON.parse and fetch
const result = JSON.parse("{}"); // unknown
```

**CAVEAT**

Use ts-reset in applications, not libraries, as it would make any project that imports your library unknowingly opt in to ts-reset.